# How to open new UIView dynamically in Xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'd like to open new UIViewController dynamically without using any storyboards and xib-files.
I have button in my application, which launches new window. This window I'm going to populate dynamically in my code.

Trying this:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(new MyCustomView(), false, null)
```

Is it a correct way for *MyCustomView()*? Seems, strange a little bit...

Comment: NavigationController.PushViewController(controllerName, true)

Comment: Thanks, InitLipton, exact the same code I'm trying now, but *NavigationController* class isn't accessible globally, only from *UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController*.

Comment: can you post the full class

Comment: no sense - it is a dummy class with just opening new View )

Answer (score 0):

From your presenting viewcontroller in the button tap handler you call PresentViewController(...). Make sure you actually instantiate a viewcontroller instead of a view.